# How do I create a script on the fly to execute w/the execution manager in Python?

Tags: python, perl, code-translation

I'm trying to translate this PERL code into Python:

```
# Create a script on the fly to execute w/ the execution manager
unlink "logger_exit_test.pl";
open my $fh, '>', "logger_exit_test.pl" or die "Unable to create 
logger_exit_test.pl";
print {$fh} <<EOF;
#!$EXECUTABLE_NAME
ISC::message( \$ARGV[0], MESSAGE => "test" );
EOF
close $fh;

chmod 0750, "logger_exit_test.pl";
```

So far, I have this piece of Python code:

```
## Create a script on the fly to execute w/ the execution manager
try:
    os.remove("logger_exit_test.py")
except OSError:
    pass

open("logger_exit_test.py", "w+")
with open('logger_exit_test.py') as fh:
   for line in fh:
       print line
       if 'str' in line:
          break

executable_name = sys.executable()

ISC.message(sys.argv[0], MESSAGE("test"))

f.close()

os.chmod("logger_exit_test.py", stat.S_IRWXU)
```

So far I've been unsuccessful with creating an executable...this fails:

executable_name = sys.executable()

Answer (score 0):

This is the perl idiom for opening a file for write ("w+"),

```
open my $fh, '>', "logger_exit_test.pl" or die "Unable to create logger_exit_test.pl";
```

These lines in perl construct the file (what is the name of the #! (shebang) program to run this file?, $EXECUTABLE_NAME),

```
print {$fh} <<EOF;
#!$EXECUTABLE_NAME
ISC::message( \$ARGV[0], MESSAGE => "test" );
EOF
close $fh;
```

You seem to be asking python to determine the path to python, but do you intend to use the python interpreter, or the perl interpreter to execute the file you constructed (you used the .py extension, so my guess is you want to use python)?

```
executable_name = sys.executable
```

This is the python idom for opening a file for write, and you will need to import the python library(ies) appropriately,

```
with open("logger_exit_test.py", "w+") as fh:
    fh.write("#!${}\n".format(executable_name))
    fh.write("#import appropriate_package as ISC\n")
    fh.write("""ISC.message( sys.argv[0],  MESSAGE("test");\n""")
#since you used with open(), close not needed,

os.chmod("logger_exit_test.py", stat.S_IRWXU)
```

Look here for how to execute the above file, [run child process from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358467/printing-all-shell-commands-fired-from-python-script-onto-console-before-execut/43358757#43358757)

Comment: Thank you, Chuck! That was indeed helpful. :)